# Write a series of piecewise linear functions that converges to $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Write a series of piecewise linear functions that converges to $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

A sequence of piecewise linear functions that converges to $f(x) = x^2$ is as follows:

For $k \in [0,j-1]$:

\begin{align*}
  f_j(x) &= \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{j} \cdot x & \text{if $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{j}$} \\
      \frac{2k+1}{j} \cdot \left(x - \frac{k}{j} \right) + \frac{k^2}{j^2} & \text{if $\frac{k}{j} \le x \le \frac{k+1}{j}$} \\
      \frac{2j-1}{j} \cdot \left(x - \frac{j-1}{j} \right) + \frac{j^2-2j+1}{j^2} & \text{if $\frac{j-1}{j} \le x \le 1$} \\
    \end{cases} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \lim\limits_{j \to \infty} f_j(x) &= f(x) = x^2 \\
\end{align*}

What would be a series of piecewise linear functions such that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty f_j(x) = f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: A thing to try is if to consider what is $f_{j+1}(x) - f_{j}(x)$. Then use that to define partial sum $g_n(x)$ (this will be quite messy since you have to take into account domains and the like) and show that this converges to $f(x)$. I am aware that this is very broad, but the object to consider is $f_{j+1}(x) - f_{j}(x)$.